# Get different model CMS fields, add them to a CMS tab

Tags: php, silverstripe

In a Silverstripe (version 3) model admin, how can I get the collection of fields from a *different* model so as to add them to this model's admin?

I have tried this using [FieldList::addFieldsToTab](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/forms/tabbed_forms/#add-multiple-fields-at-once):

```php
$loremIpsumTab = Tab::create('LoremIpsum');
$fields->fieldByName('Root')->insertAfter('Main', $loremIpsumTab);

$loremIpsumFields = (
    $this->LoremIpsum()->getCMSFields()
        ->fieldByName('Root.Main')->Fields());

$fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.LoremIpsum', $loremIpsumFields);
```

That creates the tab correctly, but moves the fields incorrectly: *all* the fields from 'Root.Main' are moved, not only those for the LoremIpsum model.

I had assumed this would interrogate the related LoremIpsum model for its CMS fields:

```
    $this->LoremIpsum()->getCMSFields()
        ->fieldByName('Root.Main')->Fields()
```

So how can I move *only* those fields for the LoremIpsum model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. What do you want to acchieve?

It seems you want to edit a has_one relation dataobject from your other dataobject. There are ready-to-use and tested modules for this scenario, e.g. https://github.com/stevie-mayhew/hasoneedit/tree/3.x , cause even if you manage to display the fields, SilverStripe assumes those values belong to  the current model and not to a relation. Then you'll have extra work to save it back etc...

Some fields in your current model and in the LoremIpsum model have the same name, e.g. ID, Title, Created. This causes problems in your code above, cause you can only have one Field for e.g. ID in a Form.

The "hasoneedit" module overcomes this by prefixing the relation's fields.

Comment: I was hoping that Silverstripe already had a way to request this, without yet another dependency. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well, SS isn't a big monolitic CMS but can be extended easily if the out-of-the-box solutions are not enough for your needs. That's why it has lots of extension points.